# how to make script that run just once per day in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make script that run functions just once per day (and I can not guarantee when exactly I will run the script)
what I'm trying to do exactly is saving the second (y) variable's output instead on number 5 located in first (y) variable to later use

```
import datetime

class daily():
 y = 5
 x = (datetime.datetime.today().day)
 if x != y:
    print("def")
    def one():
        print("one")
    def two():
        print("two")
    y = (datetime.datetime.today().day)
 elif x == y:
    print("done")
    pass
```

Comment: Where do you use `self.one` and `self.two`??

Comment: sry im just new to python and every code i write , is just by trying , the code edited

Comment: What you need is to record `day` with `open`, which will be read the next time it is executed.

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an error? Why do you assign a tuple `x = (datetime.datetime.today().day)`?

Comment: @dudulu can you show me how?

Comment: @ Dock  i do not get any error

Comment: it sounds like you are having a variable scope issue? Are you saying the value of ```y``` is not what you want it to be?

Comment: @ griffin_cosgrove , yeah something like that , the number 5 in the first line is a day's number , and i want to take the output value of the second (y) and store it instead of number 5

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

First you create a `day.json` file.

content

```
{
    "day": 5
}
```

This is an example

```py
import datetime
import json


class daily:
    y = json.load(open('day.json', 'r'))['day']
    x = datetime.datetime.today().day
    if x != y:
        print("def")

        def one(self):
            print("one")

        def two(self):
            print("two")

        y = {'day': datetime.datetime.today().day}
        json.dump(y, open('day.json', 'w'), indent=2)
    elif x == y:
        print("done")
        pass
```

I have not run this program, if there is an error, please let me know.

You can go to GOOGLE Python `open` for related instructions.

In this example, I use `.json`, you can also just use `.txt` for access.

Comment: I enjoyed helping you.